# Compile error not visible - Assuming subprocess not imported/error with code

Tags: python, discord, reddit

New to python and attempting to create a script that loads a discord bot that prints a message that is a result from a different script.

Essentially I need the flow to be. Import discord, run script.py, receive command to alter parameter of wallet address, print console response to discord bot, relays to chat.

Lots of issues but would love if someone can just point out some obvious flaws/errors as I'm stumped.

````
import discord
import subprocess
import requests, json

# Replace SCRIPT_PATH with the path to the Python script you want to run
SCRIPT_PATH = "SCRIPT.PY"

# Replace FILE_PATH with the path to the Python script you want to modify
FILE_PATH = "SCRIPT.PY"

# Replace STRING_TO_REPLACE with the string you want to replace in the Python script
STRING_TO_REPLACE = "addresses"

# Replace BOT_TOKEN with your Discord bot's token
BOT_TOKEN = "TOKEN_VALUE"

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {client.user.name}")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("!run_script"):
        # Extract the new string value from the chat command
        new_string_value = message.content.split()[1]

        # Modify the Python script to use the new string value
        with open(FILE_PATH, "r") as f:
            file_contents = f.read()
        new_file_contents = file_contents.replace(STRING_TO_REPLACE, new_string_value)
        with open(FILE_PATH, "w") as f:
            f.write(new_file_contents)

        # Run the Python script
        output = subprocess.check_output(["python", SCRIPT_PATH])

        # Send the output to the chat channel
        await message.channel.send(f"Script output:\n```\n{output.decode()}\n```")

client.run(BOT_TOKEN)

input('Press ENTER to exit')
````

Then I have this that works perfectly and prints the message

```
import requests, json

addresses = ["WALLET_ADDRESS"]

for x in addresses:
    a1 = json.loads(requests.get('https://meta-api.reddit.com/crypto-contacts?providers=ethereum&addresses='+str(x)).text)
    try:
        print(str(x)+" resolves to the user u/"+ str(a1['contacts'][list(a1['contacts'].keys())[0]][0]['username']))
    except:
        print(str(x)+" failed to resolve, unlikely vault address")

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting from us.  You haven't told us what's wrong with the code you have.  Error?  Wrong output?

Comment: Error messages are written to `stderr`. `subprocess.check_output()` captures only `stdout` by default. Read the documentation to find out how to capture `stderr` as well.

Comment: I was able to get it working. Apologies for the lack of information. It now logs into discord, receives the message and alters the string "WALLET ADDRESS". Only issue is that it doesn't run the script.py again. It simply changes this addresses = ["WALLET_ADDRESS"] string to addresses = ["changedtext"] and then nothing occurs. I need to research further as I don't want to waste any ones time.